How to fix black screen in desktop

help me to solve this problem. I got that after doing nothing.

Did you update the system sometime before this happened?

What version Virtualbox are you using? I found Virtualbox 7.1 failed with Ubuntu 24.04.1. I'm not sure if similar problems exist with Ubuntu 22.04.

It might be related to VirtualBox settings or the version you're using. Check if you're on the latest version of VirtualBox and update it if necessary. Also, try adjusting the display settings in VirtualBox by increasing the video memory or enabling 3D acceleration. If the problem persists, you could try reinstalling the VirtualBox Guest Additions or switching to a different version of VirtualBox to see if that helps.
